# VS 2013 SDK: How to set a CommandBarButton picture?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

Following the C# answer of @**Carlos Quintero** in **[this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891635/changing-a-buttons-icon-in-with-the-visual-studio-sdk)** and next reading him C# article **[here in this link](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005007.aspx)**, I've tried to follow the steps mentioned to set the `CommandBarButton.Picture` of a menu button, however, when I do it any image appears, the package does not throw any error, just the image is not shown (maybe is not properly loaded or its in bad format?)

These are the images that I'm trying to set:

[image]  [image]  [image]

And this is the code that I'm using, what I'm missing or doing wrong?:

```
Friend Sub CreateMenu(ByVal dte As EnvDTE80.DTE2)

      Dim objImageToPictureDispConverter As ImageToPictureDispConverter = Nothing
      Dim objImage As System.Drawing.Image = Nothing
      Dim objIPictureDisp As stdole.IPictureDisp = Nothing

      objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\path to resources...\Menu_Tag_Green.png")
      objImageToPictureDispConverter = New ImageToPictureDispConverter
      objIPictureDisp = objImageToPictureDispConverter.GetIPictureDispFromImage(objImage)
      objImageToPictureDispConverter.Dispose()

      ' Get a reference to the context menu of code window.
      Dim codeWindowCommandBar As CommandBar =
          DirectCast(dte.CommandBars, CommandBars)("Code Window")

      ' Add a popup command bar.
      Dim mainPopup As CommandBarPopup = 
          DirectCast(codeWindowCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, 
                                                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing), CommandBarPopup)
      mainPopup.Caption = "..."

      ' Add controls to the popup command bar.
      BtMakeCodeExample = 
        DirectCast(mainPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 
                                          Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
                                          1, True), CommandBarButton)

      BtMakeCodeExample.Caption = "My Button"
      BtMakeCodeExample.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIcon
      BtMakeCodeExample.Picture = objIPictureDisp

End Sub
```

+

```
Public Class ImageToPictureDispConverter : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.AxHost

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("{63109182-966B-4e3c-A8B2-8BC4A88D221C}")
    End Sub

    Public Function GetIPictureDispFromImage(ByVal objImage As System.Drawing.Image) As stdole.IPictureDisp

        Dim objPicture As stdole.IPictureDisp

        objPicture = CType(System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetIPictureDispFromPicture(objImage), stdole.IPictureDisp)

        Return objPicture

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a package, the user interface should be created using the .vsct file, which allows you to declare command pictures. See [Howto add icons to commands on toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165158.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using a command menu template which creates an vsct file (I explained you in other question the reason why). You think I'm doing things wrong and I should use that template, instead of an empty template like I'm using?. I only want to "manage" things inside the code editor menu.

Comment: We will continue the discussion in your "VS 2013 SDK: How to add a line separator in a CommandBarPopup menu?" thread

Answer (score 1):

The solution was really easy, just the `Style` property of the `CommandBarButton` should be set as `MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIconAndCaption` instead of `MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIcon`.